# How to loop class to property value in css LESS

Tags: css, sass, less, flexbox

I have this **SCSS** code

```
.order {
  @for $i from 1 through 3 {
    &--#{$i} { order: $i; }
  }
}
```

Which compiles to this in CSS

```
.order--1 {
  order: 1;
}
.order--2 {
  order: 2;
}
.order--3 {
  order: 3;
}
```

How to i do the same function in css **LESS**?

Comment: Duplicate of any of http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=27&tab=newest&q=%5bless%5d%20loop. And read [the docs](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@i: 1;
.order (@i) when (@i <= 3) {
    .order--@{i} {
        order: ~"@{i}";
    }
    .order(@i + 1);
}
.order (@i);
```

Result is:

```
.order--1 {
  order: 1;
}
.order--2 {
  order: 2;
}
.order--3 {
  order: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This piece of less code:

```
.order(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
  .order--@{i} {
    order: @i;
  }
  .order(@n, (@i + 1));
}

.order(3);
```

Results in that css:

```
.order--1 {
  order: 1;
}
.order--2 {
  order: 2;
}
.order--3 {
  order: 3;
}
```